# "cannot find -ljscore" while I am trying to build Qt 4.7.1 static library

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qt4, webkit

I tried to build static Qt library from the latest source, but got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljscore
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: do you use `configure, make, make install`? if so, make sure you pass to `configure` correct path where `libjscore.[a|so]` is installed.

Comment: @Dmitry, more specifically about how to pass path to configrue please? I am new to Qt and C++, thanks

Comment: `./configure --help` usually gives you the options you have.

Comment: @Dmitry, I tried that before but nothing suggested helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in Qt's build system existing since 4.7.0 and not fixed in 4.7.1. After the failing make call, you have to copy libjscore.a and libjscore.prl (don't know their exact locations, search the Qt build tree to find them, somewhere in webkit) to the lib/ folder and rerun make.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem a couple of weeks ago, and I asked Nokia's support team about it (I hold a commercial licence). Their response basically is that they don't support the use of a statically linked QtWebKit, and have no intention of fixing it :

> I'm afraid that building Qt with
>   webkit statically is not supported. We
>   don't support this configure option
>   combination and we don't test it.
>
> However the compile problem is not
>   difficult to resolve. As I tried, you
>   just have to modify the searching path
>   for libjscore.a to let it find the lib
>   file.

As Frank Osterfeld said, simply copying libjscore.a and libjscore.prl to a place where ld can find it will fix it.