# Cross Compiling Qt for Embedded Arm: libpthread.so.0 not found

Tags: qt, arm, linker-errors, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I am trying to cross compile Qt with WebKit for an embedded arm device (freescale processor). I have a arm-none-linux-gnueabi toolchain.

Qt actually compiled, but I have run into problems when trying to compile the demos, in particular the WebKit ones, which is really what I am after.

The first problem I was having was that libjscore was not found, which was an error due to the way Qt handles static builds.  Turns out you can copy the library and it works, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333102/cannot-find-ljscore-while-i-am-trying-to-build-qt-4-7-1-static-library).

Now compilation breaks again saying it can not find libpthread.so.0, which would seem to be a toolchain problem rather than a Qt problem.

Searching the directory tree in my toolchain, there are several libpthreads.  A copy of the ***find | grep libpthread*** command's output is below for reference.

```
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/vfp/lib/libpthread-2.5.so
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/vfp/usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/vfp/usr/lib/libpthread.a
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/vfp/usr/lib/libpthread.so_orig
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/vfp/usr/lib/libpthread.so
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/lib/libpthread-2.5.so
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.a
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so_orig
./arm-none-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libpthread.so
```

So it seems that there is something weird with the linker? Also, what needs to be symlinked to create the *libpthread.so.0*?

Note: the _libpthread.so_orig_ and *libpthread.so* follow this [fix](http://xc0ffee.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/linker-%E2%80%9Cld-cannot-find-liblibpthread-so-0%E2%80%B3/).

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.  I've been banging my head against a wall for two days now.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have the libraries. generally if there are multiple shared libraries (.so) they are named as such - somelib.so.1 , somelib.so.2 , where sometimes the suffix to .so might also be a version name. So i would say create a sym link from libpthread.so.0 to either libpthread.so or libpthread.so_orig or libpthread-2.5.so , it is possible all of them will work, otherwise just link to the newest libpthread.

Comment: @abhijith - Thanks for your reply.  I added a symlink from libpthread.so.0 to the libpthread-2.5.so and the linker breaks on something else now.  I am getting the error: `arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s`.  There is a libgcc_s somewhere in the toolchain directory tree.  Any ideas?

Comment: it isnt sufficient if it is 'somewhere' , it has to be in the search path of your toolchain. you can add search paths/directories to your linker using the -L option. For example , if you want the linker to search the directory /usr/local/mydir for any library files , you supply this option to the linker -L/usr/local/mydir

Comment: @abhijith - I was able to link to it correctly, but it breaks on another library.  Seems to be a common theme here. I'm going to play around with it a bit to see if I can make it happy.  I'll let you know if I run into any other problems.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: New Error...`warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`...Any idea what I am doing wrong now?

Comment: that is a warning , it is just telling you that you'll need a dll later. That won't stop compilation nor will it be a problem later on, unless you don't have glibc on the device.

Comment: Ya the linking errors out shortly after that.  All output seems to be related to that. All undefined references to like _dlclose and similar. There is a glib directory within the toolchain.  Could I be needing to add the directory with a -L possibly?? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: yes ,unless you are sure that directory is being searched for the libs, add it using the -L param. Also remember that order of specifying the libraries is important. For example if liba depends on libc then providing this to the linker fails '-lc -la' , this is the right way '-la -lc'.  For more information look at http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ld.htm . The option you need is --start-group --end-group

Comment: just verified, all those libraries are already in the path and added with -L.  I guess there is a possibility that the order is wrong, but the MakeFile is generated through Qt and qmake, so I do not think that is the case. Any ideas where to start looking next?

Comment: Hard to say , you just have to make sure all libraries are there , can't think of anything apart from that.

Comment: ya, I'm considering restarting this process on Monday...need to take a break of it for a bit I think...thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should make sure that the toolchain you built (or has been built for you) is in the same exact path it was built at.  The libraries (*.so *.a) should also be in the same original path.  It should look like this:

`<path>/bin`
`<path>/usr/lib`
`<path>/lib`

Those folders should not be moved.  The toolchain executables are in "bin" and the libraries it looks for are in "../usr/lib and ../lib".  Also, `<path>` may be hard-coded into your gcc binaries in some fashion.  Moving it around seems to break things.

Comment: Posted this from a general account and forgot to update.  The issue was indeed path related.  It actually turned out that the toolchain provider did not include all the libraries I needed in the toolchain, so I had to extract the rootfs and link to the libraries that way. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @jyore I am facing the exact same problem. Could you please elaborate your solution, or may be post it as an answer?

Comment: Man this is a blast from the past. IIRC, I mounted the embedded devices file system on my build machine and pointed the toolchain to that mount so it could use the system/kernel libraries

Answer (score -1):

Target is a raspberry PI
I copy target lib directory to myuserdirectory
target /usr/lib to my crosscompiler /usr/lib/ directorie
target /lib  my crosscompiler /lib/ directorie

I create two symbolic link:

```
ln -s /yourcrosscompilerusrlibdirectory /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
ln -s /yourcrosscompilerusrdirectory /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

and it's work for me
libpthread are in `/yourcrosscompilerusrlibdirectory`